# Working with local dependencies in Poetry (Python)

Tags: python, dependency-management, python-poetry

I am trying to set up a Python project in Windows called `my_repo1` by using `poetry` for the first time.

This `my_repo1` depends on a second repository allocated in Azure, called `my_repo2`. This repository was created the way it is (with no `poetry` or any other tool such as `pip`) and most of it cannot be changed. It was not set up so good let's say. The project `my_repo1` is structured at follows:

[image]

Since `my_repo1` depends on `my_repo2`, I decided to include it as a `[tool.poetry.dependencies]`. After reading many posts in this website, it seems `poetry` allows you to add packages based on local dependencies, so I tried many different options the type of:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
my_package2 = {path = "submodules/my_repo2/my_package2/"}
```

But as soon as I run `python3 -m poetry install`, I get the following output:

```
Directory {}\my_repo1\submodules\my_repo2\my_package2 for my_package2 does not seem to be a Python package
```

Among the possibilities I considered:

- Installing `poetry-dot-env` plugin to create a `.env` and append any new package that might appear under `submodules` in `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Problem? I do not have enough permissions to install the plugin
- Creating a Python script to modify any of the `.venv` files so that whenever the command `python3 -m poetry run/shell`, the `PYTHONPATH` variable is extended (similar to previous approach). However, I could not find the file that is always called before the `poetry run/shell` commands are called.
- Adding the `PYTHONPATH` manually so that it points to the submodules in the system. I do not like this idea at all because there might be more repositories with same folder structure. Therefore, if same submodules are used among different repositories, `Python` will only import the one that first appears in `PYTHONPATH`.
- I also tried defining the dependency from its git-based URL but I did not manage to make it work. [DOCS](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#git-dependencies)

Therefore, is there a way of fixing this local dependency? If there is no other way to fix it, I might have the possibility of adding `poetry` and `pyproject.toml` also to `my_repo2`, but the folder structure has to remain the same. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe what you want/need is to list `my_repo2` under `packages` instead, should be possible with the `from` option.